# Resource usage by Spark Receivers

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

As per [Spark Streaming Guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#important-points-to-remember),

> A DStream is associated with a single receiver. For attaining read parallelism multiple receivers i.e. multiple DStreams need to be created. A receiver is run within an executor. It occupies one core. Ensure that there are enough cores for processing after receiver slots are booked i.e. spark.cores.max should take the receiver slots into account. The receivers are allocated to executors in a round robin fashion.

I have a few doubts.

1. If a receiver is run within an executor, is it so that there is only one instance of receiver per batch interval? If not, then is there a way to decide/control the number of receivers?
2. Receivers occupy one core to read data and generate blocks. As per my understanding processing starts only after all the partitions/blocks are generated for that particular micro batch. So, doesn't the receiver free up its resource usage after all the data is read, such that the now available core can be utilized for processing? If it is so, then why

> spark.cores.max should take the receiver slots into account ??

Any help will be appreciated. I could not find an in-depth explanation on this part.